# Allure Framework: unable to use @Step , @Parameter and @Attachments annotation with TestNG and Maven already AspectJ enabled

Tags: java, maven, testng, allure

I am trying to use @Step , @Parameter and @Attachments parameters, but they are not shown in the report, @Title and @Feature are working fine.
My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>NewLookSmoke</groupId>
<artifactId>NewLookSmoke</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>NewLookSmoke</name>
<description>Smoke Test Suite for NewLook</description>
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.5</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.4.11</allure.version>
    <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\${aspectj.version}\aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${allure.results.directory}</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And below is my class testng.xml class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<test name="RegisterNewUser Test; locale: EUR">
    <parameter name="locale" value="EUR" />
    <classes>
        <class name="project.RegisterNewUser" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->


<test name="RegisterNewUser Test; locale: GBP">
    <parameter name="locale" value="GBP" />
    <classes>
        <class name="project.RegisterNewUser" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

My Java code:

```
@Features("Register User")
```

public class RegisterNewUser extends OpenAndCloseBrowser {

```
String baseURL;
String locale;
HomePage hp;
CLPPage clp;
CartPage cp;
ActionDriver ad;
HomePageElements hpe;
List<WebElement> we;
List<String> str_lst;
String str;
JavascriptExecutor jse;
boolean flag;
String locale_text;
Actions act;
PLPPage plp;
PDPPage pdp;
PickAPathPage pap;
List<String> prop;
@Parameter("Sign in successful: ")
private String flg2;

byte[] flg;

boolean flag1;  

@Parameters({"locale"})
@BeforeMethod
public void init(String locale) {

    //this.baseURL = baseURL;
    this.locale = locale;
    ad = new ActionDriver(wd);
    prop = ad.loadProperties(locale);
    this.baseURL = prop.get(1);         
    //this.CnCThreshold = CnCThreshold;
    hp = new HomePage(wd);  
    clp = new CLPPage(wd);
    hpe = new HomePageElements();
    plp = new PLPPage(wd);
    pdp = new PDPPage(wd);
    cp = new CartPage(wd);
    pap = new PickAPathPage(wd);
    act = new Actions(wd);
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    flg2 = "";
    /*
     * FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(wd)
     * .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) .pollingEvery(100,
     * TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
     */

}

@Attachment("Sign in successful: ")
public byte[] signInStatus(){


    return (flag1 + "").getBytes();

}

@Parameter("Test Parameter")
private String test;


@Title("Register user steps")
@Test(priority = 1)
public void test_SF_188to193() {
    System.out.println("****************test_SF_188to193***************");

    // HomePage Verification using value omniture variable "s.pageName"
    flag1 = hp.registerUser();
    flg = signInStatus();
    flg2 = flag1 + "";
    System.out.println(flg2);
    System.out.println(flg);
    test = " Passed";

    Assert.assertTrue(flag1, "Unable to register User");

}
```

I have searched thoroughly including the documentations on Allure official website, but i am unable to find the workaround.

Comment: Just to add, my local repository is also proper

Comment: Could you please create an example project at github to reproduce the problem? Can you try https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example ? Is it works for you?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, thanks for the reply, i wish i could, but due to security reasons and company policy i can not download git nor can i upload my project as it contains confidential data, I do have one additional doubt, if '@Feature' and '@Title' are working , does that mean AspectJ is enabled?
Also according to my understanding there must be some issue with my pom.xml

Comment: Only  `@Step` , `@Parameter` and `@Attachments` annotations require AspectJ, so I guess problem with it.

Comment: Is https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example works for you?

Comment: Yes the example works only if i run it through maven directly, but if i run it from tesng.xml, the annotations fail.
does testng.xml needs some allure listener, if so ,kindly let me know the process.

Comment: It certainly does. You should use https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-testng-adaptor/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/testng/AllureTestListener.java

Comment: Nope, listener adds via Java SPI, you should not specify it.

Comment: I guess you use some IDE plugin to run `testng.xml`? Which one?

Comment: I try to run `testng.xml` directly using Intellij Idea - all works fine, Idea use jvm configuration from `maven-surefire-plugin`

Comment: I am using Eclipse to run testng.xml, if i run it through maven surefire annoations are working fine, but not when i run testng.xml directly.
I am using eclipse for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run tests directly using an IDE, AspectJ configuration from `pom.xml` is not applied. So you need to specify it to your build configuration as extra VM options.